# programtically ingesting xl files to pandas data frame by reading filename

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pathlib

I have a folder with 6 files, 4 are excel files that I would like to bring into pandas and 2 are just other files. I want to be able to use `pathlib` to work with the folder to automatically ingest the excel files I want into individual pandas dataframes. I would also like to be able to name each new dataframe with the name of the excel file (without the file extension)

for example.

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib as pl

folder = pl.WindowsPath(r'C:\Users\username\project\output')
files = [e for e in folder.iterdir()]

for i in files:
    print(i)

['C:\Users\username\project\output\john.xlsx',
    'C:\Users\username\project\output\paul.xlsx',
    'C:\Users\username\project\output\random other file not for df.xlsx',
    'C:\Users\username\project\output\george.xlsx',
    'C:\Users\username\project\output\requirements for project.txt',
    'C:\Users\username\project\output\ringo.xlsx' ]
```

From here, i'd like to be able to do something like

```
for i in files:
    if ' ' not in str(i.name):
        str(i.name.strip('.xlsx'))) = pd.read_excel(i)
```

read the file name, if it doesn't contain any spaces, take the name, remove the file extension and use that as the variable name for a pandas dataframe built from the excel file.

If what I'm doing isn't possible then I have other ways to do it, but they repeat a lot of code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `pathlib` and `re`

we can exclude any files that match a certain pattern in our dictionary comprehension, that is any files with a space.

```
from pathlib import Path
import re 
import pandas as pd

pth = (r'C:\Users\username\project\output')

files = Path(pth).glob('*.xlsx') # use `rglob` if you want to to trawl a directory.


dfs = {file.stem : pd.read_excel(file) for file in 
                   files if not re.search('\s', file.stem)}
```

based on the above you'll get :

```
{'john': pandas.core.frame.DataFrame,
 'paul': pandas.core.frame.DataFrame,
 'george': pandas.core.frame.DataFrame,
 'ringo': pandas.core.frame.DataFrame}
```

where `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` is your target dataframe.

you can then call them by doing `dfs['john']`

Comment: Will this not also bring the other excel file (files[2]) in as a df?

Comment: @KevOMalley743 nope, they aren't in the test output I've provided either. they are excluded by the `if` statement in the dictionary comprehension